# Google Slides API cannot read content of slide from an instance of page (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-slides-api

I am trying to read text from a slide presentation (as a work around to copying and pasting since all of the slides have the same exact format). When using this code:

```
res.data.pageElements.forEach((file) => {
    let textElements = file.shape.text.textElements;
    textElements.forEach(function(each){
        console.log(each.textRun.content);
    });
});
```

Even though the response says its there if I use `console.log(res.data.pageElements.shape.text.textElements.textRun)`, referencing the way I did, returns `undefined`. 
 Please let me know if there is a solution to my problem, or if you know a work around to  copy a side from presentation X to presentation Y. Thanks in advance!

**There is an issue tracker for this:** https://issuetracker.google.com/36761705

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(each.textRun);`?

Comment: It returns a portion of `res` in which  `content` has text in it. @ic3b3rg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? From your script, I supposes that you retrieve `res` using `slides.presentations.pages.get()`.

#### Modification point:

- Objects with and without `res.data.pageElements.shape.text.textElements.textRun` are existing in the elements of the returned object.

  - `res.data.pageElements` which has no property of `shape`.
  - `res.data.pageElements.shape` which has no property of `text`.
  - `res.data.pageElements.shape.text` which has no property of `textElements`.
  - `res.data.pageElements.shape.text.textElements` which has no property of `textRun`.

I think that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

```
slides.presentations.pages.get({
  presentationId: presentationId,
  pageObjectId: pageObjectId,
}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.data.pageElements.forEach((file) => {
      if (file.shape && file.shape.text && file.shape.text.textElements) {
          let textElements = file.shape.text.textElements;
          textElements.forEach(function(each) {
          if ("textRun" in each) {
            console.log(each.textRun.content);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

#### Note:

- I think that you can also use `if ("shape" in file && "text" in file.shape && "textElements" in file.shape.text) {` instead of `if (file.shape && file.shape.text && file.shape.text.textElements) {`.
- If you retrieve `res` using `slides.presentations.get()`, please modify `res.data.pageElements.forEach((file) => {})` to `res.data.slides.forEach((slide) => {slide.pageElements.forEach((file) => {})})`.

If I misunderstand about your issue, please tell me. I would like to  modify it.

Comment: That works, in theory. It detects that all content is `undefined`.

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot to change the variables for `presentationId` and `slideObjectId`! It works! (TYSM I've been working on this for  a few weeks!)

Comment: @Arkin Solomon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.